# MonitoredTrainingSession with SyncReplicasOptimizer Hook cannot init with placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

1. I construct my network with tf.keras.Input as Input layer.

   > input_image = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name='input_image')
2. follow network definition, I define my optimizer like this:
   [image]
3. then, I pass the hook to MonitoredTrainingSession
   [image]
4. finally, when runing to create MonitoredTrainingSession, a placeholder bug raising:

   > tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_image' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?,3]
   > this exception is raised from `ready_value = sess.run(op)` in `session_manager.py` called by `hook.after_create_session(self.tf_sess, self.coord)`

Any idea about SyncReplicasOptimizer with placeholder is appreciating.

Comment: got a workaround solution by using `placeholder_with_default`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the place causing the problem:
there exists conflicts in my code between SyncReplicaOptimizer and Batch Normalization Updates.

```
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    self.train_op = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step)
```

This style update will raise the exception, but after separating the control dependencies, run train_op and update_ops simultaneously instead can avoid this problem.

But anyway, I have not figure out the insight reason or a descent way to solve the problem yet.